# After page refresh ngx-translate in angular4 is swiching back to english

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have switched my site language to spanish in angular4 using ngx-translate,so when i refresh the page it switches back to english language.
So,is there any way to keep spanish as a  language of my site,after i refresh the page using ngx-translate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you set your language **spanish** then store in **localstore**

Like ::

below code when you select switched your site language to spanish

```
 this.translate.setDefaultLang('es');
 this.translate.use('es');
 this.localStorage.setItem("language","es");
```

and below code when you first time set language

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('language')){
        translate.setDefaultLang(localStorage.getItem('language'));
        translate.use(localStorage.getItem('language'));
    }else {
         translate.setDefaultLang('en');
         translate.use('en');
         localStorage.setItem("language","en");
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the browser can clear ALL localstorage items if the storage quota is reached!